# ¿Cómo agilizar la ejecución de una consulta así; pude emplearse una subconsulta?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT FContable, FSalida, HSalida, TBoleto, FBoleto, Tipo, TServicio, Importe, Area_de_Venta, 
                    Origen, Destino, FVenta, HVenta, IF(Corrida = '000000','BOLETO_MANUAL',Corrida) as run FROM db_ventas.tb_vtas 
                       WHERE Empresa_Corrida <> '' and Importe > '0'
                          and Area_de_Venta = '$a_venta' and FContable between '$fecha1' and '$fecha2' 
                          ORDER BY Corrida, Origen, Destino;
```

La estructura de carpetas que tengo es estilo MVC, de los forms se mandan los valores a otro archivo y de ese segundo, se llaman las consultas con los parametros.
La consulta tarda un poco en ejecutarse en el programa, quisiera saber si como esta armada se puede hacer en sub-consulta para agilizarse. 
Y como pudiera evitar que a vecez salga el mensaje de php de:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Me atrevería a decir que una condición en la consulta hace que sea mas pesada, Me ha sucedido con algo similar, haz las condiciones a parte de la consulta, has varias pruebas, obviamente debes hacer pruebas constantemente para saber si aun sigue funcionando la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un JOIN, son más eficientes que las subconsultas:

```
SELECT FContable, FSalida, HSalida, TBoleto, FBoleto, Tipo, TServicio, Importe, Area_de_Venta, Origen, Destino, FVenta, HVenta, IF(Corrida = '000000','BOLETO_MANUAL',Corrida) AS run 
JOIN db_ventas.tb_vtas ON Empresa_Corrida <> ''
AND Importe > '0'
AND Area_de_Venta = '$a_venta'
AND FContable BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2' 
ORDER BY Corrida, Origen, Destino;
```